# How to get value of li value of two div's using jquery

Tags: jquery

Please find the below structure.

**When i click a button i need to get the li value of two div.**

For example, Let us consider **in first div i have selected test2** and **in second div i have selected test 8** and **when i click the button i need to get the value as 558 and 561**

How can i do this using jquery.

```
<div class='parent'>test 1</div>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
    <li value="0">All</li>
    <li value="556">test 1</li>
    <li value="558">test 2</li>
    <li value="560">test 3</li>
    <li value="561">test 4</li>
    </ul>  
</div>

<div class='parent2'>test 6</div>
<div class="list2">
<ul>
<li value="0">All</li>
<li value="556">test 5</li>
<li value="558">test 6</li>
<li value="560">test 7</li>
<li value="561">test 8</li>
</ul>  
</div>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't even remotely understand this question. Can you provide an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"? There's no way to "select" an `li` in Javascript...

Comment: dont you need an `input type=checkbox` inside each of your `li`s?

Comment: @@lonesomeday: Actual case is when i click the li the value will be replaced by the above div. for example if i click test 6 it will be replace by the above parent div..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`li` tags cannot be selected and do not have a `value` attribute defined. It would be more correct to use radio buttons or a dropdown to select a value. If you want to use li you could keep 2 global variables with the corresponding selected values which will be updated everytime some li is clicked:

```
var value1 = '0',
    value2 = '0';

$('.list li').click(function() {
    value1 = $(this).attr('value');
});

$('.list2 li').click(function() {
    value2 = $(this).attr('value');
});

$('#someButton').click(function() {
    alert('value1 = ' + value1 + ' | value2 = ' + value2);    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about "select" box instead of "li" tag, you can easily grab the select variable with jQuery using .val()